# Who decided to remove the "username" from the new FB Graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

The "username" being deprecated it documented, yes. That is not the question, the question is how to get it and -furthermore- I wonder why Facebook has made such a terrible choice and removed the username. Hundreds of applications that rely on the username to create accounts on their service will be broken.

Shall we stick with the V.1 API which will be around until the end of April 2015?
By far not the best solution but Facebook might be irrelevant by then anyway.

Solution: ask the user for a username besides the actual Facebook login? - In my opinion, that makes the Facebook login completely pointless, again.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Facebook's roadmap and not a programming question for the API

Comment: Could your app use its own username entry box instead of relying on there being no collision between Facebook's usernames and the existing usernames in your own app?

Comment: Just came back here after a while. @Igy how is this off-topic? - It is no where indicated (or tagged) that this was an API programming question. Furthermore, the road map does also not play much of a role here. It was a plain question about the use of a certain feature of the API. I guess you working at FB has made you sensitive to talking about it, no worries, I get that.

Comment: This was something that would previously have fallen under the "primarily opinion based" close reason; with the current options it's off topic as it's not a specific and answerable programming question (which everything here should be: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score -1):

The link field is still available which includes the username. You could use something like .replace('https://www.facebook.com/','') in javascript to keep just the username.

"link": "https://www.facebook.com/username",

Comment: I think they figured that out as well:

"link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/101523595/"

Comment: What I do now; is generate a username on the fly using the actual user's first name (which is always available) and the FB user ID.